# Solved: Amcharts5 tree not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, amcharts, amcharts5

I'm having an issue where my amcharts5 tree isn't loading properly. Essentially the data is getting fetched from my API. And then I am transforming it into something that Amcharts 5 is expecting for a tree. My problem is that on the first couple of renders nothing happens, but if I go into my source file and change something and click save. Then the chart renders correctly.

Here is the React code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import * as am5 from "@amcharts/amcharts5";
import * as am5hierarchy from "@amcharts/amcharts5/hierarchy";

import "./Chart.css";

const URL = "http://localhost:8000/get-journeys";

const Chart = () => {
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState("");

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(URL);
    const data = await response.json();

    const newData = [
      {
        name: data.title,
        children: Object.keys(data)
          .filter((key) => key.startsWith("mr-") || key.startsWith("client-"))
          .map((key) => ({
            name: key,
            children: data[key].map((item) => ({
              name: item.title,
            })),
          })),
      },
    ];
    setChartData(newData);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    let root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

    let series = root.container.children.push(
      am5hierarchy.Tree.new(root, {
        valueField: "value",
        categoryField: "name",
        childDataField: "children",
      })
    );

    console.log("rendering");

    series.data.setAll(chartData);

    series.nodes.template.setAll({
      draggable: false,
      toggleKey: "none",
      cursorOverStyle: "default",
    });

    return () => {
      root.dispose();
    };
  }, []);

  return <div id="chartdiv"></div>;
};

export default Chart;
```

The JSON from my API looks like:

```json
{
  "title":"Base operation",
  "invitable":false,
  "keyValues":{
    
  },
  "mr-tkr":[
    {
      "clone":"mr-tkr",
      "title":"Client B: Total Knee Arthroplasty",
      "invitable":true,
      "keyValues":{
        "client":"client-b",
        "joint":"knee"
      }
    },
    {
      "clone":"mr-tkr",
      "title":"Client A: Total Knee Arthroplasty",
      "invitable":true,
      "keyValues":{
        "client":"client-a",
        "joint":"knee"
      }
    }
  ],
  "mr-thr":[
    {
      "clone":"mr-thr",
      "title":"Client B: Total Hip Arthroplasty",
      "invitable":true,
      "keyValues":{
        "client":"client-b",
        "joint":"hip"
      }
    },
    {
      "clone":"mr-thr",
      "title":"Client A: Total Hip Arthroplasty",
      "invitable":true,
      "keyValues":{
        "client":"client-a",
        "joint":"hip"
      }
    }
  ],
  "client-b-tkr":[
    {
      "clone":"client-b-tkr",
      "title":"Client B: Partial Knee Arthroplasty",
      "invitable":true,
      "keyValues":{
        "client":"client-b",
        "joint":"knee",
        "partial":true
      }
    }
  ],
  "mr-op":[
    {
      "clone":"mr-op",
      "title":"Total Knee Arthroplasty",
      "invitable":true,
      "keyValues":{
        "joint":"knee"
      }
    },
    {
      "clone":"mr-op",
      "title":"Total Hip Arthroplasty",
      "invitable":true,
      "keyValues":{
        "joint":"hip"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And the JSON once it has been mapped into something for amcharts

```json
{
  "name":"Base Operation",
  "children":[
    {
      "name":"mr-tkr",
      "children":[
        {
          "name":"Client B: Total Knee Arthroplasty"
        },
        {
          "name":"Client A: Total Knee Arthroplasty"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"mr-thr",
      "children":[
        {
          "name":"Client B: Total Hip Arthroplasty"
        },
        {
          "name":"Client A: Total Hip Arthroplasty"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"client-b-tkr",
      "children":[
        {
          "name":"Client B: Partial Knee Arthroplasty"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"mr-op",
      "children":[
        {
          "name":"Total Knee Arthroplasty"
        },
        {
          "name":"Total Hip Arthroplasty"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've just noticed that if I add the `chartData` state variable to my `useEffect` dependency it renders infinitely. `}, [chartData]);`

Not really sure what I can do to either make my data render correctly the first time. Or how to prevent infinite re-rendering. Maybe I should split this into two components, or something else.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Nevermind I think I found a way of fixing it. I've created a parent component that calls the API and then passes the data down to the chart as props.

Comment: You know why that works and the above code doesn't? Because immediately after you call fetchData the data hasn't returned yet. But good for you that your error helped you build code that's cleaner than your first stab at it!